# Why is the reaction between the two free radicals below not observed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

All the below reactions are observed:
[image]

Why is this one not happening?
[image]

Comment: Cyclopropylmethyl radical rearranges to homoallyl radical. There may be some kinetic considerations that prevent the self-self coupling. It's possible that the first reaction proceeds through a more complicated mechanism with the same product.